# Can I modify a Tcl struct::graph while walking it?

Tags: tcl

Tcl `struct::graph` has a `walk` command and I'd like to use that to remove nodes and cleanup data accessible by node attributes, e.g. widget names. The documentation says nothing about what can and cannot be done while walking the graph, so I was wondering how it works if I start removing arcs adjacent to walked node.

Here is my intended walk command (almost finished, may be bugs in it):

```
proc csp_scene_walk_remove {mode g n} {
  set canvas [$g get canvas]
  foreach arc [$g arcs -adj $n] {
    $canvas delete [$g arc get $arc widget]
  }
  $canvas delete [$g node get $n widget] [$g node get $n widgetanno] [$g node get $n widgetanno].bg
  $g node delete $n
}
```

I imagine it just might work IF `walk` works on the actual graph object and not a copy, data is internally copied at just the right moment etc etc.

Q: What is the behavior of stuct::graph `walk` if modifying the graph while walking it?

---

**EDIT:** The command would seem to do what I want using it like this:

```
# destroy all nodes downstream with associated widgets
mygraph walk $node -order post -type dfs -dir forward -command csp_scene_walk_remove;
```

But I can't tell if that is implementation defined behavior as seen by Tcllib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what you're doing will work, you're right to be suspicious because concurrent modification bugs are horrible to sort out. The simplest method is going to therefore be to accumulate a list of nodes to remove as you traverse the tree, then use `$graph node delete {*}$theNodes` to delete them all afterwards. Except we can keep the list of nodes we're accumulating in the graph itself, which simplifies things a bit.

```
proc csp_scene_walk_remove {mode g n} {
    upvar #0 $nodeAccumulator nodes
    set canvas [$g get canvas]
    foreach arc [$g arcs -adj $n] {
        $canvas delete [$g arc get $arc widget]
    }
    $canvas delete [$g node get $n widget] [$g node get $n widgetanno] \
            [$g node get $n widgetanno].bg
    $g lappend deadNodes $n
}

mygraph set deadNodes {}
# Order of traversal is unimportant; nodes remain until afterwards
mygraph walk $node -command csp_scene_walk_remove
# NB: Expanding substitution is very useful here!
mygraph node delete {*}[mygraph get deadNodes]
mygraph unset deadNodes
```

I'd be more tempted to give each node's canvas items a common tag (e.g., the node ID!) and then use that to delete them so that I wouldn't need to track the canvas IDs of quite so many things, but that's up to you…

Comment: About tags: yes, it is on my todo-list to organize them like that instead. Remains from my first lines of tk.